# How to fix SQL Error [306] [S0002]: The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator?

Tags: casting, sql-server-2017

I have problem when using "=" (equal to operator) to compare sql server text data type.
This is my query look like

```
 SELECT * FROM dbeplanningv3.dbo.usulan_dpr
 WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR, evaluasi) is null 
 or 
 trim(CONVERT(VARCHAR, evaluasi)) = '' ORDER BY [detail] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS  
 FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

as you see in my script above. I am doing casting data type with this `CONVERT(VARCHAR, evaluasi)`
but still not work and I get error `SQL Error [306] [S0002]: The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted,`
this is a part of my table structure
[image: table usulan_dpr]
help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query:

```
SELECT * FROM dbeplanningv3.dbo.usulan_dpr
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR, evaluasi) is null 
or 
trim(CONVERT(VARCHAR, evaluasi)) = '' ORDER BY [detail] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS  
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

only `ORDER BY [detail]` could cause this error, so I will assume `[detail]` is of type `text` (this column isn't visible on your screenshot). To avoid the error, you should convert it to varchar(max):

```
SELECT * FROM dbeplanningv3.dbo.usulan_dpr
WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR, evaluasi) is null 
or 
trim(CONVERT(VARCHAR, evaluasi)) = '' ORDER BY convert(varchar(max), [detail]) ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS  
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

But the important question is why on SQL Server 2012 you still use `text` data type? You should convert these to `varchar(max)` and avoid casting them all the time.

Also, this cast `CONVERT(VARCHAR, evaluasi) is null` is pointless. You can check `evaluasi is null` directly.

Comment: I am so sory about my wrong information about sql server version who I tagged in my question. 
I am already check my sql server version using 'select @@version' evidently the real version is sql server  2017 
Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU9-GDR) (KB4293805) - 14.0.3035.2 (X64)

Comment: I don't realy know  why my friend using text data type not varchar. we just developing and debuging  another friend who not present in this time.